# can't remove files from trash

Tags: files, filemanager, trash, administrator

I deleted some files from usr/shr (basically some themes)
and now i am not able to empty my trash 
It is saying "You do not have sufficent permissions to delete the file".

Answer (score 0):

Run nautilus as root by opening a terminal and typing `sudo -H nautilus`. Then you should be able to delete the file. (Substitute in your file manager (e.g nemo, caja, dolphin) as necessary).

Comment: not working it is saying - ' CANNOT DISPLAY CONTENT OF trash:///"

Comment: That's because the Trash folder is associated with a specific user. As a root you can browse to that folder directly. In Nautilus type press CTRL+L and enter the path of the Trash, as in: /home/<user>/.local/share/Trash/files/ where <user> is your username